# Why is a relative file name used in Flymake recipes?

Tags: python, emacs, relative-path, flymake

EmacsWiki, among other sources, gives this sort of recipe to add Python checking to Flymake:

```
(defun flymake-pylint-init ()
  (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                     'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
         (local-file (file-relative-name
                      temp-file
                      (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
    (list "epylint" (list local-file)))
```

Why is the use of `local-file` as a relative filename useful or desirable? I instead use:

```
(defun flymake-flake8-init ()
  (unless (file-remote-p default-directory)
    (let ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                      'flymake-create-temp-with-folder-structure)))
      `("flake8" ("--max-complexity=10" ,temp-file)))))
```

It seems to work fine with the absolute `temp-file`.

Comment: Who knows… probably `epylint` does something special when given a relative file name, probably it's just over-engineering.  Code from the EmacsWiki should generally be treated with caution.

Comment: I've seen it in all sorts of flymake init functions, so it probably didn't originate with `epylint`. I assume it is just cargo cult Elisp.

Comment: Yeah, likely.  Probably most Flymake recipes were just copied and adapted from others, without real thinking.  Btw, shameless plug,  but you may want to take a look at [Flycheck](https://github.com/lunaryorn/flycheck), which is a Flymake alternative with a built-in syntax checker for flake8.  Disclaimer:  I am the author of this project.

Comment: It was already on my todo list :)

Comment: Cool :) Please tell me how you like it and what could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I am also confused this code snippet. But at least it is buggy and causes errors in the case that the working directory is represented by a symlink pathname. In such case, elisp function `buffer-file-name` simply returns symlink pathname of current buffer, rather than the real pathname. `temp-file`, however, is the real pathname of the flymake temporary file. So `temp-file` and the value of `(file-name-directory buffer-file-name)` are actually inconsistent. This discrepancy makes the relative pathname incorrect.

Comment: I ended up switching to Flycheck so I no longer worry about this problem.